# TYPO3 add one blank space between two words in input value

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm using TYPO3 8.7.9.
With the following TS I prefill the value of an input field in frontend:

```
plugin.tx_powermail {
settings {
    setup {
        prefill {
            name = COA
            name {
                10 = TEXT
                10.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|first_name
                10.dataWrap = | &nbsp;   --- this doesn't work.

                20 = TEXT
                20.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|last_name
            }
         }
      }
  }
}
```

I need a blank space between first and last name. DataWrap doesn't help here, because the HMTL code is shown in the input field. 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested by myself; maybe this could work too:

```
plugin.tx_powermail {
settings {
    setup {
        prefill {
            name = TEXT
            name.value = {TSFE:fe_user|user|first_name} {TSFE:fe_user|user|last_name}
            name.insertData = 1
            }
         }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Posting the question was the half way to the solution. When I tried first 'noTrimWrap' it wasn't successful but now it works. So the solution is very easy:

```
plugin.tx_powermail {
settings {
    setup {
        prefill {
            name = COA
            name {
                10 = TEXT
                10.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|first_name
                10.noTrimWrap = | | |

                20 = TEXT
                20.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|last_name
            }
         }
      }
  }
}
```